# Utilising TLS within internal search domains

Tags: tls

Consider a domain such as `service.internal.domain`. By setting the internal search domain to `.internal.domain`, users can access the address simply by typing `service` into a browser.

However, due to the TLS certificate being issued to `service.internal.domain` and not `service`, TLS domain validation will fail. Is there a way around this i.e. making Chrome or similar browsers consider the fully qualified domain?

I do not have an internal CA authority setup, instead I use Lets Encrypt, so I cannot issue certificates for `service`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to redirect all simple hostnames to their fqdn equivalent with this server block.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    if ($host !~ ".internal.domain") {
        return 301 https://$host.internal.domain$request_uri;
    }
}
```